# Could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reflection, spring-data-jpa

I have a Partner Enitity, Partner can have many roles called PartnerRoles. One of the partner role can be an Affiliate. Have used JPA Inheritance Mapping. The following exception is being thrown when tried to fetch a partner. Spring Data JPA CRUD Repository is being used to do the CRUD Operation. There are no issues with Create and Update.

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.tracebucket.partner.domain.PartnerRole.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.tracebucket.partner.domain.PartnerRole.id
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:303)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.findOne(Unknown Source)
    at com.tracebucket.crm.test.repository.PartnerRepositoryTest.testFindById(PartnerRepositoryTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.tracebucket.partner.domain.PartnerRole.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.generateHashCode(CollectionKey.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.getLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1074)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne(SimpleJpaRepository.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.tracebucket.infrastructure.ddd.domain.BaseEntity.id to java.lang.Long
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 85 more
```

Java class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTNER")
public class Partner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected String title;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected String image;

    @Column(name = "WEBSITE")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected String website;

    @Column(name = "PARTNER_CATEGORY", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "ENUM('INDIVIDUAL', 'GROUP', 'ORGANIZATION') default 'ORGANIZATION'")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected PartnerCategory partnerCategory;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
    private Organization owner;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER__ID")
    protected Set<PartnerRole> partnerRoles = new HashSet<PartnerRole>(0);
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTNER_ROLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "PARTNER_ROLE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class PartnerRole extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "PARTNER_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER__ID"))
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);
}

@Entity(name = "PARTNER_AFFILIATE")
@Table(name = "PARTNER_AFFILIATE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PARTNER_ROLE__ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PARTNER_AFFILIATE")
public class Affiliate extends PartnerRole implements Serializable {
    private static final String simpleName = "Affiliate";

    @Column(name = "BUSINESS_NAME")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String businessName;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_INCORPORATION")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Date dateOfIncorporation;

    @Column(name = "LOGO")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String logo;

    @Column(name = "WEBSITE")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private String website;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name="AFFILIATE_PERSON",
            joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="AFFILIATE__ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="PERSON__ID", referencedColumnName="ID", unique=false) }
    )
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>(0);
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes  = {ApplicationTestConfig.class, JPATestConfig.class})
public class PartnerRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PartnerRepository partnerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

    private Partner partner = null;

    private Organization organization = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{

    }

    private void createPartner() throws Exception{
        partner = PartnerFixture.allRoles();
        //organization = organizationRepository.save(partner.getOwner());
        partner = partnerRepository.save(partner);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() throws Exception {
        createPartner();
        partner.getPartnerRoles().clear();
        partner = partnerRepository.save(partner);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, partner.getPartnerRoles().size());
        partner.getPartnerRoles().add(CustomerFixture.standardCustomer());
        partner = partnerRepository.save(partner);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, partner.getPartnerRoles().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById() throws Exception {
        createPartner();
        partner = partnerRepository.findOne(partner.getAggregateId());
        Assert.assertNotNull(partner);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception{
        createPartner();
        Assert.assertNotNull(partner.getAggregateId());
    }  
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    public BaseEntity(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my team, we found the answer to be "add `@Transactional` to the test case".

This is per @SSmd's (somewhat buried) comment above.

Comment: Is there equivalent to this annotation in hibernate with Java EE ? I face exact same issue but not using Spring !!